# SQL Server 2005 connection with java. 

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, sql-server-2005, jdbc

Needed help : connecting SQL Server2005 with java. I had put the dll file in system32. I'm using sqljdbc_2.0 drivers

```
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2338)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1917)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1061)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.product.DAO.userDAOImpl.GetRemotePID(userDAOImpl.java:10029)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.product.DAO.userDAOImpl.getServiceList(userDAOImpl.java:8191)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.product.action.BillGenerationAction.execute(BillGenerationAction.java:272)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
02:29:11,937 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What authentication schemes are configured for the SQLServer instance?

Comment: it doesnt contain any user name and password.. but still getting the error

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2007/06/18/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx

Comment: @srikanth, firstly, the error is not because you are sending the user name and password, or otherwise. Secondly, there are details that missing in the question. It would be better if we know what is the version of the JDBC driver in use, and the JDBC connect string that you are using. Also, try setting the debug level to TRACE (or equivalent) for Tomcat to see if you can get more information about the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you aren't using jtds?  http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You're using integrated authentication. Did you follow instruction in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms378428%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to use integrated security?

If you specify a username and a password, instead of `integratedSecurity=true` in the connection string do you get connected?

Comment: @vineeth: I'm using JBoss 4.0 with eclipse IDE Helios. I'm using sqljdbc_2.0 drivers and dll associated with it.

Comment: if i specify user name and password instead of integrated security still it wont be connected

Comment: no... the error will be.. Unable to login by the username='sa' .. but i had given windows authentication and I'm not using any username and password

Comment: To connect using usernames and passwords (e.g. `sa`) with SQL Server usernames you must enable it in the configuration. By default this option is disabled. `Server Properties --> Security --> enable SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode`

Answer (score 0):

This is based on data gleaned from all over this post and from MSDN. The error presented here is typically encountered due to an underlying issue. In most cases, the problem has to do with the `java.library.path` environment variable that is used by the JVM to locate any native libraries to be loaded. This environment variable may already be set by JBoss, in which one needs to append the location of the DLL to it; if not, the environment variable needs to be set when starting JBoss.

Now, this might not be the case, and therefore, it is recommended to get JBoss to write INFO and TRACE level events if that is not the case. The underlying issue typically tends to be reported as a TRACE level log entry.